# How to change my the From: address in mutt?

Tags: email, mutt

When I use mutt under Ubuntu like below, my email address is shown as maemo@maemo-TomXue. I want to change it but didn't find how to do, who could help me? Thanks!

```
y:Send q:Abort t:To c:CC s:Subj a:Attach file d:Descrip ?:Help

From: maemo maemo@maemo-TomXue
  To: hello@what.com
  Cc:
 Bcc:

Subject: 111 Reply-To: Fcc: ~/sent Mix: Security: None

-- Attachments - I 1 /tmp/mutt-maemo-desktop-1000-4182-199622
```

Answer (score 7):

Either start reading up on mutt's [configuration](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/), or `export EMAIL=my.address@example.com` from your `.bashrc'

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, it's most likely that the best way to address your situation is by editing `~/.muttrc` appropriately. However, for those who stumble on this question looking for a "one-time" way to change the value of the 'From' header, you can simply use <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

The most standard way to do this is to use a ~/.muttrc file and add the following to it:

```
set from = "my_preferred_address@whatever.com"
```

And this should solve the problem... Other useful settings to use are:

```
 set realname="My RealName"
 set use_from=yes
 set envelope_from ="yes"
```

Have a look [here](http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttFaq/Header) for a discussion of the correct way to set "From" and other matters...