# How to change my Ubuntu email address setting?

Tags: email, ubuntu-email-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change my the From: address in mutt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92934/how-to-change-my-the-from-address-in-mutt)

When I use mutt under Ubuntu like below, my email address is shown as maemo@maemo-TomXue.
I want to change it but didn't find how to do it?

```
y:Send  q:Abort  t:To  c:CC  s:Subj  a:Attach file  d:Descrip  ?:Help

    From: maemo maemo@maemo-TomXue
      To: hello@what.com
      Cc:
     Bcc:
 Subject: 111
Reply-To:
     Fcc: ~/sent
     Mix: 
Security: None


-- Attachments
- I     1 /tmp/mutt-maemo-desktop-1000-4182-199622
```